# How can I filter the nested lists?

Tags: c#

I have a strange situation. I have a class like this:

```
public class Node
{
   public object Data { get; set }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to create a filter for Active property on instance. So I don't want to display when Active property is false. How could I resolve this situation? I'll accept any solution(recursion, linq,etc.).

THX for everybody.

Comment: What do you mean? `if(node.Active) { Display(node) } else { /* don't display */ }`

Comment: Knowing the UI framework you are using and how you are applying this `Node` class to the tree view would help...

Comment: What you've tried and how it does not work would help too...

Comment: I corrected the question. I just want to filter the instance of Node class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a readonly property called `ActiveNodes` which goes something like this:

```
public class Node
{
   public object Data { get; set }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<Node> ActiveNodes {
       get {
           foreach (var node in this.Nodes)
               if (node.Active)
                   yield return node;
       }
   }
}
```

and then use the `ActiveNodes` property to do whatever you usually did with the `Nodes` property.

As @wudzik mentioned in the comments section, you can also achieve the same effect in a more functional manner like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Node> ActiveNodes {
    get {
        return this.Nodes.Where(node => node.Active);
    }
}
```

Comment: easier -> `Nodes.Where(x=>x.Active)` + you don't need to use `this` here

Comment: @wudzik Point taken. However, unexperienced users may find `lambdas` to be somewhat misterious. Also I tried to make no assumptions about the target CLR's version. `Iterators` were introduced in 2.0.

Comment: Which version of .NET supports `IEnumerable<Node>` but not LINQ?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Touche :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class Node
{
    public object Data {get;set;}
    public bool Active {get;set;}
    public List<Node> Nodes {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Node> ActiveNodes
    {
        get 
        {
            return Nodes.Where(n => n.Active);
        }
    }
}
```

in your `TreeView` use `ActiveNodes` instead of `Nodes`